# How to Subtract fields in filemaker?

Tags: database, filemaker

I have added a field11 total. It has to be the value field10 - field9 - field8 - field7. How to write the code and view result in field11?

Comment: May we see what you have tried so far? Usually questions that link to the manual or other prior research are more successful, since people prefer to help folks who have made an obvious effort first.

Comment: Thx for your answer. I was solved. I was issue with type: instead calculations I had numbers.

Comment: @Balan: please don't edit posts to add "please help" and "thanks" - we edit that stuff out anyway.

Comment: Glad you solved it Kristijan!

Answer (score 0):

Calculations need to be defined using FileMaker's field type = "calculation" under Manage Database, whether the desired result is a number or text or other.

http://www.filemaker.com/help/12/fmp/html/create_db.8.17.html